# How to use flowVars inside wildcard filter and expression filter Mule

Tags: regex, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Is it possible to use the flowVariable inside wildcard or  expression filter directly.
I need to stop the flow based on the flow Variable value.

Example: My flow Variable name `keyValue` have the value like `customer/feed/h26/h56` in this  'h26/h56' should set dynamically but `customer/feed` is constant always. I need to set my filter only after '/feed/' if it contain any characters.

```
  <flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="c:/in"/>
     .......( Many component)
    <set-variable variableName="keyValue" value="#[customer/feed/h26/h56]" doc:name="Variable"/>
     .......( Many component)    
     <message-filter doc:name="Message">
        <wildcard-filter pattern="customer/feed/+*" caseSensitive="true"/>
    </message-filter>
</flow>
```

Used `+` in pattern to check whether it contain one or more characters.

Also I used expression filter, not sure how to use flow Variable inside the filter expression.  Could you please help me on this.

I don't want to use property filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expression filter instead, and since your expression is simple just use the startsWith method of String.

for example

```
    <expression-filter expression="flowVars.keyValue.startsWith('customer/feed/')" doc:name="Expression"/>
```

this will allow messages

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please give me the expression for dymanic entry. Actually if  keyValue have 'customer/feed/' alone I should drop the message. Only if it have some extra characters after it, it should proceed further 'customer/feed/something'. Can you  please provide expression for that.

Comment: Here, using regex.  <expression-filter expression="flowVars.keyValue.matches('/customer/feed/.+')" doc:name="Expression"/>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't use `wildcard-filter` on `flowVars` directly because it applies a wildcard pattern to the message payload. Here is the implementation excerpt from the `org.mule.routing.filters.WildcardFilter` class

```
public boolean accept(MuleMessage message) {
    try {
        return accept(message.getPayloadAsString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("An exception occurred while filtering", e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

So it is clear that the `WildcardFilter` converts the payload to a String and applies the filter.

Also, in the case of `regex-filter`, it applies a regex pattern to the message payload. Here is an implementation excerpt from the `org.mule.routing.filters.RegExFilter`

```
public boolean accept(MuleMessage message) {
    try {
        return accept(message.getPayloadAsString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

Now coming to your question, you can very well use `expression-filter` as suggested by Tyrone Villaluna. But you may want to include the expression in start and end signs like `^customer/feed/.+$`

And so

```
<expression-filter expression="flowVars.keyValue.matches('^customer/feed/.+$')" />
```